# Get Magento installation id?

Tags: magento

When the Magento installation is done, it will give you a code which you should remember. Is there a way to get that code later in case I forgot it?

Thanks!

Comment: That actually is the crypt key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this here
app/etc/local.xml

```
<crypt>
<key><![CDATA[your_key]]></key>
</crypt>
```